# Summing over repeated indices in a dictionary and returning the resulting values

Tags: python, dictionary, indices

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {
    'inds': [0,   3,   7,   3,   3,   5, 1],
    'vals': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
}
```

I want to sum over the inds where it sums the repeated inds and outputs the following:

```
ind:  0    1    2    3*    4    5    6    7

x == [1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

I've tried various loops but can't seem to figure it out or have idea where to begin otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> indices = [0,3,7,3,3,5,1]
>>> vals = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
>>> d = defaultdict(float)
>>> for i, idx in enumerate(indices):
...     d[idx] += vals[i]
... 
>>> print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {0: 1.0, 3: 11.0, 7: 3.0, 5: 6.0, 1: 7.0})
>>> x = []
>>> for i in range(max(indices)+1):
...     x.append(d[i])
... 
>>> x
[1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

Using `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> z = sorted(zip(indices, vals), key=lambda x:x[0])
>>> z
[(0, 1.0), (1, 7.0), (3, 2.0), (3, 4.0), (3, 5.0), (5, 6.0), (7, 3.0)]
>>> for k, g in itertools.groupby(z, key=lambda x:x[0]):
...     print(k, sum([t[1] for t in g]))
0 1.0
1 7.0
3 11.0
5 6.0
7 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `x` to be a list of sums for every value (say `i`) in the range of `'inds'` in `d` (min to max) of the `'vals'` in `d` that have a `inds` matching `i` at the same position.

```
d = {
    'inds': [0,   3,   7,   3,   3,   5, 1],
    'vals': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
}

result = [sum([val for ind, val in zip(d['inds'], d['vals']) if ind == i]) 
          for i in range(min(d['inds']), max(d['inds']) + 1)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[1.0, 7.0, 0, 11.0, 0, 6.0, 0, 3.0]
```

No libraries required. Although the list comprehension isn't exactly easy to read - it's fairly efficient and matches the description.

A breakdown of the list comprehension into its parts:

- `for i in range(min(d['inds']), max(d['inds']) + 1)` just gets `i` to range from the smallest value found in `d['inds']` to the largest, the `+ 1` takes into account that range goes up to (but not including) the second passed to it.
- `zip(d['inds'], d['vals'])` pairs up elements from `d['inds']` and `d['vals']` and the surrounding `for ind, val in ..` makes these pairs available as `ind, val`.
- `[val for ind, val in .. if ind == i]` generates a list of `val` where `ind` matches the current `i`

So, all put together, it creates a list that has the sums of those values that have an index that matches some i for each i in the range of the minimum `d['inds']` to the maximum `d['inds']`.